# fetch data to table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, for-loop, fetch

I have a table filled with data (fetch from url) and that data is

```
{
  "id": "145127236",
  "mygoals": "success",
  "future": "high",
  "dole": {
    "Key": "fhd699f"
  }
}
```

Under the table I have a select box (the data of it also fetched from url) its data is this

```
[{
    "id": "1111",
    "mygoals": "getmarried",
    "future": "married",

  },
  {
    "id": "2222",
    "mygoals": "getmarried",
    "future": "married",

  },
  {
    "id": "33333",
    "mygoals": "getmarried",
    "future": "married",

  }
]
```

what I want to achieve is that when user chooses from select box, then table should fill with that specific data which was chosen, i'm beginner with javascript learning, this should be easy task don't know how to do it, here is my code

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">

   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <style>
     </style>
   </head>

   <body>
     <div class="container">
       <table class="table table-responsive-sm ">
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <th>id</th>
             <th>mygoals</th>
             <th>future</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody id="t">
         </tbody>
         <thead>
           <tr>
             <th>id</th>
             <th>mygoals</th>
             <th>future</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody id="t2">
         </tbody>
       </table>
       <select id="Select" name="name"></select>
     </div>
     <script>
       fetch("https://asdasd.free.beeceptor.com/a", {
         method: "GET",
         headers: {
           "x-api-key": "p*****w"
         }
       }).then(res => {
         res.json().then(t => {
           console.log(t);
           var p = "";
           var p2 = "";

           p += "<tr>";
           p += "<td>" + t.id + "</td>";
           p += "<td>" + t.mygoals + "</td>";
           p += "<td>" + t.future + "</td>";
           p2 += "<td>" + t.id + "</td>";
           p2 += "<td>" + t.mygoals + "</td>";
           p2 += "<td>" + t.future + "</td></tr>";

           document.getElementById("t").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", p);
           document.getElementById("t2").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", p2);
         })
       }).catch(err => {
         console.log("ERROR: " + err);
       });

       fetch("https:******.com/", {
         method: "GET",
         headers: {
           "x-api-key": "p*****w"
         }
       }).then(res => {
         res.json().then(t => {
           for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
             var s = document.getElementById("Select");
             var o = document.createElement("option");
             option.text = t[i].id + ' ' + t[i].mygoals;
             s.add(o);
           }
         })
       })

     </script>
   </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Did you want to replace the table data with the selected data or to add more to the table and keep the old data too

Comment: @Ivan86 replace the data

Comment: Damn, take it easy on getting married! :) On a serious note can we try putting all the data in a variable, change the values there and repopulate?

Comment: @LearningEveryday haha :) yes if it makes it easier, it would be good if its easy code for beginner to learn from it

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repeating yourself when you update the table, you can make an `updateTable` function that takes in data from your fetch. To update the table with the select, you can use `select.addEventListener('change', function(){updateTable(data)})`

here is an example that should do what you're looking for:

```
// populate table with new data
function updateTable(data, values) {
  const tbody = document.getElementById("t");
  // clear existing data from tbody if it exists
  tbody.innerHTML = "";
  var p = "";
  p += "<tr>";
  values.forEach(value => {
      p += "<td>" + data[value] + "</td>";
  })

  tbody.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", p);
}

// populate select options
function updateSelect(data, values) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var s = document.getElementById("Select");
    var o = document.createElement("option");
    // add data to option
    values.forEach(value => {
        o.textContent += data[i][value] + ' '
    })
    s.appendChild(o);
  }
}

// fetch initial data and populate table
fetch("https://asdasd.free.beeceptor.com/a", {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "x-api-key": "p*****w"
  }
}).then((res) => {
  res
    .json()
    .then((data) => {
      updateTable(data, ['id', 'mygoals', 'future']);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("ERROR: " + err);
});

// fetch optional data and update select options

// define dataArray to store additional data you fetch later
let dataArray;

// fetch additional data
fetch("https:******.com/", {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "x-api-key": "p*****w"
  }
}).then((res) => {
  res.json().then((data) => {
    // store additional data in dataArray
    dataArray = data;
    // update select options
    updateSelect(data, ['id', 'mygoals']);
  });

// add event listener to trigger when new data is selected
document.getElementById("Select").addEventListener("change", function (event) {
  // capture the ID
  const chosenID = event.target.value.split(" ")[0];

  // get the data matching that ID
  const chosenData = dataArray.filter((data) => data.id === chosenID)[0];

  // update table with newly selected data
  updateTable(chosenData, ['id', 'mygoals', 'future']);
});
```

`updateTable()` and `updateSelect()` work the same way, the second parameter is an array of ids that you would like to use. This allows you to change the what data you want displayed and/or what order it is displayed.

Let me know if you need clarification

Comment: it works just one problem, in my 'Real' select box data has different names than here for example here "   p += "<td>" + data.id + "</td>";
  p += "<td>" + data.mygoals + "</td>";
  p += "<td>" + data.future + "</td>"; " this is good but when i want to update the table it should update it to this : "   p += "<td>" + data.id + "</td>";
  p += "<td>" + data.avain+ "</td>";
  p += "<td>" + data.name + "</td>"; "

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but if you want to change the data output, you just need to change the following portion accordingly:

```
  p += "<tr>";
  p += "<td>" + data.id + "</td>";
  p += "<td>" + data.mygoals + "</td>";
  p += "<td>" + data.future + "</td>";
```

Comment: As long as your actual data has an `id` property, and you keep `o.textContent = data[i].id`, you can change the output (the code you referenced) to whatever you'd like.

Comment: My point is your code is working but the updating part should be different names, and if i change it to different names like you said in comments, i will not have my default table data in it

Comment: I see. I updated my answer code to expand on the `updateTable()` and `updateSelect()` functions. You can input whatever properties/keys you want e.g `updateTable(chosenData, ['id', 'avain', 'name']);`

Comment: I'm having problem here "updateTable(data, ['id', 'mygoals', 'future']); ". i want to add more to it and it should go to here cuz its next "<thead> <tr> <th>id</th> <th>mygoals</th> <th>future</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody id="t2"> </tbody>" its just adding it to "<tbody id="t"> ", same problem here : "updateTable(chosenData, ['id', 'mygoals', 'future']); ".And when updating the table how can i update name of those also i mean these : " <th>id</th> <th>mygoals</th> <th>future</th>" to something else?